# HTML/Jquery question about Canvas resizing - $(window).resize vs $(window).load/$(document).ready

Tags: jquery, canvas, processing, autoresize, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on an app that'll run using HTML5's canvas element. I have code working to resize the Canvas to fit the size of the window as it resized as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
</script>
```

However, I want my canvas to be fully sized from the get-go, not just when somebody resizes the screen. For some reason, when I copy the code above, except I change `$(window).resize` to `$(window).load` or `$(document).ready`, the canvas does not get set to the size of the window to begin with.

Does anybody see something wrong with what I'm trying to do that I'm not seeing, or have any other ideas on how to achieve this?

Best, and thanks in advance,
Sami

EDIT:

It would probably be good to note that I'm loading a ProcessingJS sketch into the canvas. I don't know whether the time that it takes for that to load ends up having an impact on things or not, but I figured I might as well make a mention of this...

Comment: `ready` works: http://jsfiddle.net/zxSDG/. However, why are you using jQuery and `document.getElementById`?

Comment: using $('#canvas') resizes the canvas by stretching everything instead of giving more resolution for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with resizing through `.width`/`.height` is that jQuery uses CSS for this. If you want to have more pixels for your canvas, use the `width`/`height` properties of the canvas instead. CSS will stretch it, HTML will increase the resolution.

```
$("#canvas")
    .attr('width', $(window).width())
    .attr('height', $(window).height());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jdjxa/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    $("#canvas")
        .width($(window).width())
        .height($(window).height());
}

$(function() {
    // initial resize when the page has loaded
    resizeCanvas();

    // bind the resize event to the window
    $(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ANSrY/13/

Comment: naa, this doesn't seem to make a difference... in fact, your code actually just stretches the canvas instead of resizing it. that said, if i replace the code within your resizeCanvas() function with my old code, i end up with working code, except that I'm having the same problem as before.

Comment: Okay, I noticed you updated your question mentioning you use ProcessingJS. Could you post a snippet of the code you use to create the Processing canvas? You should be able to use [`Processing.size()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/size_) when you create the canvas, passing to it the width and height of the document. Then bind the `resize()` event as before, calling `Processing.size()` yet again. Hard to offer a concrete answer without seeing your code though.

Comment: i'm just using something like as follows: `<canvas id="canvas" width="1100" height="800" data-processing-sources="processingFile.pde"></canvas>` the imported processing.js script takes care of the rest. 

I'm a little confused as to how to use the `Processing.size()` function to create the canvas... would you be able to explain how to do that? Also, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You should be able to get the Processing instance using `var processingInstance = Processing.getInstanceById('canvas');`. After that, calling `processingInstance.size($(window).width(), $(window).height());` should resize the canvas to the window dimensions. If that works it shouldn't be too hard to incorporate that into `resize()` and `$(function()` events.

Comment: oh that i know how to do, and have been doing already post-canvas-size-changing. i misunderstood what you wrote above. just to make sure that i understand you fully - you're saying that changing the processing sketch size should also change the canvas size? i'll try this out when i get back to work mode...

Comment: Judging from the demo's I've been looking at, yes. Take a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/processingjs/browse_thread/thread/051e9c9b0f720492/39a9a2d8ab10b541) and [this](http://anthonymattox.com/full-browser-processing-js), might help you a bit further. I have no hands on experience with ProcessingJS myself, just going with what I read from the documentation and other resources.